# Is there a way of collecting user inputs on firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm currently creating a mobile application with Android Studio (Java) that searches for an item on Amazon and returns the direct link for the product to the user. But is there a way to save user inputs in Firebase so that the user could check search history with it? Or would I need to use something different?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to use Firebase to store the data. That's the whole point of Firebase's Realtime-Database or Cloud Firestore. You can read more about it [over here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data) from the official documentation. Basically, what you can do is after returning the direct link to the user, just write it to Firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to store the data in Firebase as a way to check search history.

You can read more about how to [integrate Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) into your Android Studio Project from [their documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup), but for your purposes, you can use the below code after setting it up.

**Writing the links:**

```
DatabaseReference dbref = FirebaseDatabase().getInstance().getReference("Search History");
//Write the link to Firebase.
dbref.push().setValue(Map.ofEntries(entry("Link", "<LINK HERE>")));
```

**Reading the links:**

```
DatabaseReference dbref = FirebaseDatabase().getInstance().getReference("Search History");
dbref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot child : dataSnaphsot.getChildren()){
            //Link is the link from Firebase.
            String link = child.child("Link").getValue().toString();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew how to set Firebase up for Studio, but didn't know how to use it yet.